# Ethers.js event firing question

Tags: events, ethers.js

I've got a simple contract that fires an event when a method is called. On my ethers.js client in an html page I've got the following code executed when the page is loaded:

```
        voterContract.on("StartVote", (from, question, choice_a, choice_b, choice_c, finishTime, event) => {
            console.log("StartVote EVENT", from, question, choice_a, choice_b, choice_c, finishTime, event);
            alert("Start vote event received! with data: " + from + " " + question + " " + choice_a + " " + choice_b + " " + choice_c + " " + finishTime);
        });
```

This works when the event is fired for the first time. However whenever I reload the page I am still getting the same event fired alert even though no new StartVote events have been performed. Any idea why is this? Is there a way for me to capture only new StartVote events (i.e only the ones that are fired after the page has been loaded) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Found it. This is related to the issue on https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2310

> Keep in mind in v5 the events are scanned for starting in the current block, so if the current block has that event it will show up.

To fix it I need to use the following snippet to listen for events after the current block:

```
provider.once("block", () => {
    factoryContract.on('TokenCreated', newToken);
});
```

Using that it works fine.