# Same event triggering action more than once using useEffect and Ethers.js

Tags: solidity, events, event-handling

I am trying to listen to a smart contract event, but my event listener is getting triggered more than once per event.

The event is being emitted and returns two strings. The event is declared as `event UpdatedMessages(string oldStr, string newStr);` and it gets emitted with no issues.

I tried to use the same solution as in [Ethers.js event firing question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117469/ethers-js-event-firing-question) with no success.

the relevant part of the code is

```
  let [provider, setProvider] = useState(null)
  let [contract, setContract] = useState("");
  let [network, setNetwork] = useState("");
  let [signer, setSigner] = useState(null)

  const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
    provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
    setProvider(provider)
    network = await provider.getNetwork()
    setNetwork(network)
    //const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
    //setAccount(accounts[0])

    signer = provider.getSigner();
    setSigner(signer)

    // Javascript "version" of the smart contracts
    contract = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].helloWorld.address, HelloWorld, signer)
    setContract(contract)

  }

  const addSmartContractListener = async () => {
    if (network) {
      provider.once("block", () => {
        contract.on("UpdatedMessages", (old, data)=>{
          console.log(old, data)
        })
      })
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    addSmartContractListener();
    loadBlockchainData();
  }, [])
```

Any ideas of what am I missing?

The project is available on my GitHub at https://github.com/Benjovengo/event-listener

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved my problem.

```
  const addSmartContractListener = async () => {
    if (network) {
      provider.once("block", () => {
        contract.once("UpdatedMessages", (old, data)=>{
          console.log(old, data)
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

Now the function console.log(old, data) is called one time per event emitted.